# In Hybris CCV2 the pages are getting redirected to login page

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I have my site deployed in CCV2 SAP CX2011 version. Almost all of my requests redirects to login page, sometimes it autologins & redirects to actual url which I was accessing but sometimes I have to specifically login.
What I see in network tab is that the call "current?lang=en&curr=EUR" is getting cancelled but later automatically the same call goes through with same bearer token

Comment: There is a patch being backported to 3.4 and 3.0 (other backports are coming too within the next few days) addressing oath issues that may fix your issue: https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/commit/65abf026ba71b5785942953e213a99c5ab75a91a
Can you try upgrading to a version with the patch and see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 0):

SAP Spartacus is 100% API driven and its user session management is done with help of refresh token and access token issued by Commerce backend.

When users login Spartacus for the first time, a new refresh token together with the access token is send back to Spartacus. The access token is stored in browser local storage and refresh token is stored in memory for security reasons.

Both token can be expired, whose expiration time is maintained in Hybris Administration Console with properties oauth2.refreshTokenValiditySeconds(default: 30 days) and oauth2.accessTokenValiditySeconds(default:12 hours).

Please check this url for details.

When Spartacus sends OCC request to Commerce server, the access token is appended to http request via interceptor. If access token actually expires, Commerce will send error response like Access Token expires, then Spartacus will request a new access token with refresh token, and re-try the failed request automatically once a new access token is got. All such activities are happening under the hood, completely transparent to end user. There will be no user error message displayed in Spartacus UI.

On the other hand, if refresh token itself expires, user will be redirected to the login page, and has to maintain user name and password once again. Once logged in, Commerce issues a new refresh token and the scenario can continue.

So please kindly check the token expiration time configuraed in your Hybris Administration console if they are correctly maintained, or check fix mentioned by Caine.

Best Regards,
Jerry